# How to convert COM dispid to memberid in .NET?

Tags: c#, com

I have a "System.Collections.ArrayList" (from mscoree.dll) with CLSID {6896b49d-7afb-34dc-934e-5add38eeee39} and also I have TypeLib for it. For example, this TypeLib has co-class "IList" with function "Add" where MEMBERID is 0x60020002.

I checked with help of "GetIDsOfNames" that MEMBERID is different from DISPID for the same function "Add". DISPID is "0x60020020" (see last 2 digits).

The problem is I need to get member name having only DISPID and dispatch interface. When I use "GetNames" with DISPID I don't get anything, although in other libs everything is fine. On the other hand, if I use MEMBERID, I get the desired result "Add". I also can't parse typelib to get member names, cuz MEMBERID is not eq DISPID.

How could I convert DISPID to MEMBERID? Or might be it is possible to get member name using DISPID?

**UPDATE 2022-08-16**

Added example to demonstrate:

1. I have "IDispatch" interface and make first call to "GetIDsOfNames" with parameter "Add". The result is **0x60020020**.
2. Then I make more calls to get class info:

```
IDispatch -> QueryInterface(IID_IProvideClassInfo) -> GetClassInfo(...) -> GetTypeAttr(...) -> guid
```

Result guid is: CLSID_System.Collections.ArrayList {6896B49D-7AFB-34DC-934E-5ADD38EEEE39}

3. I'm going to open OLE/COM object viewer and see that ArrayList is a coclass with 6 interfaces, where the only IList interface has method "Add" with Id == **0x60020002** (see last 2 digits are **different** from the above).

I do really expect to see here 0x60020020 same as the result of call to GetIDsOfNames. But id is different.

Moreover, when I ask id of methods "Contains" and "Clear", I get 0x60020021 and 0x60020022, but not 0x60020003 and 0x60020004 from the Typelib.

Where am I wrong?

P.S. I checked both mscorlib.tlb and mscoree.tlb. All of them have same id (0x60020002) for "Add".

Comment: Either you've written down the IDs correctly, or you queried different interfaces.

Comment: `IList` shouldn't be a `coclass`

Comment: That's not possible.  Run OleView.exe from the Visual Studio command prompt, File > View Typelib command to see what you can expect.  Note that it is mscorlib.tlb, not mscoree.tlb.  You'll see that the default interface for ArrayList is _ArrayList and is intentionally empty.  So no surprise with what you found out.  It does implement IList, you'll see that you can retrieve its Add() method.  Very unclear why this matters.

Comment: I've updated question and added example.

Comment: Are you aware that only `IUnknown` acts like virtual inheritance, with a single interface pointer resulting no matter what sequence of query interface (acts like a cast) you use?  You can get different interface pointers for `IDispatch` depending on whether you go `ArrayList` -> `IDispatch` or `ArrayList` -> `IList` -> `IDispatch`.  Make sure you are querying `GetIDsOfNames` for the same interface you are inspecting in the Typelib Viewer.

Comment: That is to say, your bullet #1 cannot be step #1, you need to tell us how you got that `IDispatch` pointer.

Comment: I've got IDispatch pointer from "vbscript.dll" in function InvokeDispatch during simple script execution "Set a=CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList"); a.Add "N"". Does this make sense?

Comment: @Krio: Well ok.  From your `IDispatch`, do not directly call `GetIDsOfNames`.  Instead, `QueryInterface` for `IUnknown` then `IList` then `IDispatch`, and then call `GetIDsOfNames`.  Your object has an `ArrayList.Add` method and a `IList.Add` method, and they don't have the same `MEMBERID`/`DISPID`.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have a sneaking suspicion that "the default interface for ArrayList is _ArrayList and is intentionally empty" is not actually empty, and the `dual` attribute is a lie.  It does inherit from `IDispatch` and it appears the `0020` DISPID for `Add` is coming from this `_ArrayList` interface, while `0002` DISPID is for `Add` in the `IList` interface (which actually is a `dual` interface).

Comment: This document describes everything you have observed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/com-callable-wrapper  Note that "For the class interface, generation of DispIds is based on the position of the member in the interface" is **only** true for the class interface (`_ArrayList`), and not for `IList`.

Comment: It also says "To avoid breaking late-bound COM clients when using the class interface, apply the ClassInterfaceAttribute with the ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch value. This value implements a dispatch-only class interface, but omits the interface description from the type library. Without an interface description, clients are unable to cache DispIds at compile time" which explains why you cannot find `0x60020020` in the type library.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've checked with "IUnknown then IList then IDispatch, and then call GetIDsOfNames" and got the same result 0x60020020 as above. However, you are right with a link to an article. This explains why I've got 0x60020020.
So, does it mean that no way to get member name using DISPID in this case?

Comment: @Krio: I may have phrased it wrong.  `IList` inherits from `IDispatch`, so you can call `GetIDsOfNames` directly on the `IList` pointer, without using QueryInterface to hop from `IList` to `IDispatch`.  Can you try again, calling `(ptrToIList)->GetIDsOfNames()` ?

Comment: On the other hand, if you're looking for a function name that exists only in `ArrayList` and not in `IList`, for example `Sort` or `TrimToSize`, then yes it's correct you cannot have DISPID values for the `_ArrayList` interface stored in advance.  The type library intentionally doesn't include a description for `_ArrayList`, as explained in the above quote.  And if you got a `DISPID` from `IList`, you can't use it with `_ArrayList`, you can only use it with `IList`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried "(ptrToIList)->GetIDsOfNames()". Yep, I've got 0x60020002. Thanks, now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is absolutely forbidden.

[The documentation of `MEMBERID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/ace8758f-ee2b-4cb6-8645-973994d12530) says

> The `MEMBERID` of an `IDispatch` interface **MUST** be the same as its `DISPID`

If you haven't made any mistake transcribing the `MEMBERID` and `DISPID`, they must be from different types.  When viewing `ArrayList` through COM goggles, you'd have a `coclass` for ArrayList, an `interface` for the ArrayList class, and interfaces for each .NET interface implemented by ArrayList.  More than one of these have a method named `Add`.

Comment: I've updated question and added example.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the logic of the DISPID assignment function in the "mscorwks.dll" library and found that:

**DISPID is not the same as MEMBERID.**

DISPID Value is assigned dynamically in the function:

```
mscorwks.private: void __cdecl ComMTMemberInfoMap::AssignDefaultDispIds(void)
```

Given the listing of the function, we can find that it operates on an array of class methods and assigns a DISPID to each method in order, starting with the first one.

The first method is always constant 0x60020000:

```
00007FFB19A8F67F | 4C:8D69 40          | lea r13,qword ptr ds:[rcx+40]
00007FFB19A8F683 | BF 00000260         | mov edi,60020000
```

The value of each subsequent DISPID increases by one. The member "Add" gets the value 0x60020020. There is no connection to TypeLib member ids.

With this information, we understand that the call to "GetIDsOfNames" produces the correct result 0x60020020. Thus, we cannot guarantee that by comparing DISPID and MEMBERID from TypeLib we will get the desired method name "Add".

Comment: `DISPID` *is* the same as `MEMBERID`, but you have more than one dispinterface on the same object with an `Add` method, and each of these has its own set of values.